Connect to Create a New Unity Catalog using a onprem postgres database connect

Have datbricks on azure platform with admin acces.
I have serverless sql warehouse where i have imported some csv data into a catalog.
Now i need to access postgres data on onprem linux box.
Need to connect this db from datbticks add connection to create a new catalog.
I would like to use databeicks genei to acces the tables added from posgres db into the catlog.

How do i procced now.
